# Invalid loop variable type expected Contact was ContactHistory

Tags: apex, batch

Here is my requirement:

I have a batch class that I wanted to invoke when there is a change in the field of Contact. Basically I have 3 objects (Contacts, Items and Lists) When there is a change in the Contact field, I want to add contact and associated lists to the Item Object. Consider "custom" as my field on Contact.

Here is my code

```
global class BatchUpdate implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
    {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

     return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ContactId,Contact.Email,Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail,Contact.custom__c,OldValue,NewValue FROM ContactHistory WHERE Field = 'custom__c' AND CreatedDate >= N_DAYS_AGO:10]);
    }
          global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope){

    //Query to get all lists to map with contacts
            List<Lists__c> l1 = [Query List1];

            List<Lists__c> l2 = [Query List2];

            List<Lists__c> l3 = [Query List3];
    //

            List<Item__c> ilist1 = new List<Item__c>();
            Set<Item__c> setlist1 = new Set<Item__c>();
            List<Item__c> ilist2 = new List<Item__c>();
            List<Item__c> ilist3 = new List<Item__c>();

            Map<Id,Id> ctitem= new Map<Id,Id>();
            List<Id> pclist= new List<Id>();

    //Map each contact with associated lists

             for(ContactHistory ct: scope){
                 if((ct.NewValue =='Test1' && ct.OldValue =='Test')||
                    (ct.NewValue == 'Test2' && ct.OldValue =='Test')||
                    (ct.NewValue =='Test3' && ct.OldValue =='Test')){
                        for(Lists__c l : li){
                         ctitem.put(ct.ContactId,l.id);
                            ilisting.add(l.id);

                    }
             }

    // Query list of items to get if the combination of contact and List are already in the Item

            List<Item__C> ilistnn = [select id, Contact__c, Lists__c from Item__c where Contact__c =:ctitem.keyset()];
        }          
           for(Id keyId : ctitem.keyset()){
            for(Id pf : ilisting){

    //Add the rest of the lists that are associated with the contact

                if(!ctitem.keyset.contains(pf)){                

                    Item__C ic1 = new Item__c();
                    pc1.Contact__c = keyId;
                    pc1.Lists__c = pf;
                    setlist1.add(pc1);
                    ilist.addall(setlist1);
                }
             database.insert(ilist);
            }
        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch class is on `ContactHistory` object i.e. in your `start` method you queried on `ContactHistory` that means that `Database.QueryLocator` will return `List<ContactHistory>` in the `scope` variable, but in your `execute` method, you have used the `type` of `scope` variable as `List<Contact>` which is incorrect.

Because you used `List<Contact>` as `type` for `scope` variable (in execute method declaration) and you are using `ContactHistory` as loop variable i.e. `for(ContactHistory ct: scope)`, it will give you compile time error.

You will have to correct the below line in your code so as to fix this issue.

Replace below line

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope)
```

with

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ContactHistory> scope)
```

Or you can also make is as general `sObject` like below

```
global void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
```

Comment: I had another issue with the same code "Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements" I tried moving the initialization of object inside the loop but had no luck

Comment: I used a set and then added a list because I had duplicates getting created, so wanted to avoid them